# Return value of Redux middleware

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

Redux guide [suggests](https://redux.js.org/advanced/middleware) that `next(action)` should be returned from middleware functions but doesn't clearly document middleware API.

Here's [React + Redux example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-6ddkrn):

```
const fooMiddleware = store => next => action => {
  return next({ ...action, foo: 'foo' });
};

const foobarMiddleware = store => next => action => {
  return next({ ...action, foobar: `${action.foo}bar` });
};

...

const store = createStore(
  reducer,
  applyMiddleware(fooMiddleware, foobarMiddleware)
);
```

It seems to work as intended regardless of `return` in middlewares.

Is return value necessary in Redux middleware functions and why? How exactly can it affect Redux application? If the lack of it can break things, I'd appreciate a specific example that illustrates the problem. Are there conditions under which a demo above could become broken?

Comment: @markerikson Please, reopen the question. Dupe question isn't as specific as this one and lacks specific example, so the answer in dupe question.

Comment: A "specific example" would be if you have `applyMiddleware(myMiddleware, thunk)`, a thunk function attempts to return a promise, and the code that dispatched the action tries to call `dispatch(myThunkReturningAPromise()).then( () => {} )`.  In that example, the promise never gets returned, and the code will throw an error because "then is not a function".

Comment: @markerikson So missing returns can't make anything fail with barebone Redux with no middlewares, correct? It behaved ok no matter what return value was in my case.

Comment: Right, that's what I said in my linked answer.  What _might_ fail is _if_ any code is specifically relying on the return value from `dispatch()`, including a  return value from a given middleware.  If there's no code that cares about what `dispatch()` returns, then there's nothing that would fail.

Comment: @markerikson Thanks for clarifying that.

Answer (score 3):

Because the middleware works as a chain of *functions* where each middleware *function* dispatches the *action* to the next *function* in the chain, each middleware *function* needs a dispatch *function*. The middleware functions receive these dispatch functions when the composing function is called, with the nth middleware function receiving `store.dispatch` and each subsequent *function* receiving the previous middleware function as its dispatch.

A middleware is simply a function with the signature

```
storeInstance => 
functionToCallWithAnActionThatWillSendItToTheNextMiddleware =>
actionThatDispatchWasCalledWith => 
valueToUseAsTheReturnValueOfTheDispatchCall
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Can you provide an example where return value will matter, based on the example listed in the question?

Comment: @estus For example in your foobarMiddleware Middleware you have some logic that if action has foo add something else remove something

Comment: Also you should read this very good article https://medium.com/@jacobp100/you-arent-using-redux-middleware-enough-94ffe991e6

Comment: Thanks for the link, seems valuable. I've checked and it seems like it works in opposite way, the results from 2nd middleware (foobar) are returned to 1st middleware (foo), https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-xflpdh . Seems intuitive, that's how middlewares work in other libs. But it's unclear how this feature can be used in practice. Notice that updated actions aren't propagated to props after they were dispatched. Do you have any ideas?